# Ruby/Typhoeus : set ssl_verifypeer global

Tags: ruby, ssl, typhoeus

is it possible to set `ssl_verifypeer` in typhoeus global? Something like:

```
Typhoeus::Config.ssl_verifypeer = false
```

Answer (score -1):

No it is not. Unfortunately. I've been thinking about Session support for a while now. Something like

```
Typoeus::Session.new(ssl_verifypeer: false) do
  Typhoeus.get("https://www.example.com")
end
```

But right now there is no way to configure it globally.